# Find sale of other categories when a user has bought in some category?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the below format. It is the sale date at user_id level for different categories.

```
id  cat_1   cat_2   cat_3
1     1      10      100
2     2      0        0
3     0      20       0
5     3      0        0
6     4      0        0
9     5      0        0
10    0     30       200
11    6     0        300
12    7     0         0
13    8     40      400
```

I want data like what is the sale of other categories when a user has bought in some category. eg. what is the sale of cat_2 and cat_3 when cat_1 is not equal to 0.

```
      cat_1  cat_2  cat_3
cat_1   36   50     800
cat_2   9   100     700
cat_3   15  80      1000
```

It can be done in excel but looking for a method via pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = np.empty([df.shape[1], df.shape[1]])
for indexi,i in enumerate(df):
    for indexj,j in enumerate(df):
        arr[indexi][indexj] = sum(df[df[i]>0][j])
```

Comment: So I change my solution. Or your solution working and my no? I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary comprehension with sum of filtered rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`), join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
#if id is not index
df = df.set_index('id')
df = pd.concat({x:df[df[x].gt(0)].sum() for x in df.columns}).unstack()
#alternative
#df = pd.concat({x:df[df[x].gt(0)].sum() for x in df.columns}, axis=1).T

print (df)
       cat_1  cat_2  cat_3
cat_1     36     50    800
cat_2      9    100    700
cat_3     15     80   1000
```

Comment: @NitinKansal - Sure, check my profile, run code for my eamil and send me csv.